# background-position-y doesn't work in Firefox (via CSS)?

Tags: html, css, firefox

In my code the `background-position-y` doesn't work. In Chrome it's ok, but not working in Firefox.

Anyone have any solution?

Comment: Good news everyone! Looks like `background-position-x` and `-y` will be supported in Firefox 49: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position-x#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 120):

If your position-x is 0, there's no other solution than writing :

```
background-position: 0 100px;
```

background-position-x is a non-standard implementation coming from IE. Chrome did copy it, but sadly not firefox...

However this solution may not be perfect if you have separate sprites on a big background, with rows and cols meaning different things... (for example different logos on each row, selected/hovered on right, plain on left)
In that case, I'd suggest to separate the big picture in separate images, or write the different combinations in the CSS... Depending on the number of sprites, one or the other could be the best choice.

Comment: Thanks, great catch. I just went and removed my uses of -x and -y so that I'm standards compliant. :)

Comment: As always with FF... wierd

Answer (score 19):

## Use this

```css
background: url("path-to-url.png") 89px 78px no-repeat;
```

## Instead of this

```css
background-image: url("path");
background-position-x: 89px;
background-position-y: 78px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: funny that firefox doesn't support "Instead" markup, but yeah, it works.. ty ;)

Answer (score 16):

Firefox 49 [will be released](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/49)—with support for `background-position-[xy]`—in September 2016.  For older versions up to 31, you can use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Browser_compatibility) to achieve positioning the background on a single axis similar to using `background-position-x` or `background-position-y`.  CSS variables reached Candidate Recommendation status [in December 2015](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/).

The following is a fully cross-browser example of modifying background position axes for sprite images on hover:

```
:root {
    --bgX: 0px;
    --bgY: 0px;
}

a {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-position: var(--bgX) var(--bgY);
}

a:hover, a:focus { background-position-x: -54px; --bgX: -54px; }
a:active   { background-position-x: -108px; --bgX: -108px; }
a.facebook { background-position-y: -20px; --bgY: -20px;  }
a.gplus    { background-position-y: -40px; --bgY: -40px;  }
```

Comment: It's been almost a year in limbo, with Firefox still being the only implementation. Not a good sign.

Comment: @BoltClock: It's [under consideration](https://status.modern.ie/cssvariables) by Microsoft, with a fair few votes behind it, and development [just (re)started](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465126) for Chrome.  However, for this particular use case, CSS variables can be employed today, as the only browser that implements them is the only one that needs them to simulate background-position-x/y.

Comment: Cool! Better late than never I guess :)

Comment: Just noticed - [CSS Variables is on its way to CR](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Mar/0498.html). Also cool.

Comment: hello 2016! still no implementation... :\

Answer (score 15):

> `background-position-y :10px;` is **not working** in Firefox web browser.

**You should follow this type of syntax:**

```
background-position: 10px 15px;
```

10px is bounded to "position-x" and 15px bounded to "position-y"

*100% working Solution*

Follow this [URL](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-position&preval=50%25%2050%25) for more examples

Comment: This works in ff v. 38. Should be marked as the correct solution. It achieves exactly what the question is after

Answer (score 3):

```
background: url("path") 89px 78px no-repeat;
```

Will not work if you want a background along with the image. So use:

```
background: orange url("path-to-image.png") 89px 78px no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use **background-position** directly?

**Use:**

```
background-position : 40% 56%;
```

**Instead Of:**

```
background-position-x : 40%;
background-position-y : 56%
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```css
a {
    background-image: url(/image.jpg);
    width: 228px;
    height: 78px;
    display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -78px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> However this solution may not be perfect if you have separate sprites on a big background, with rows and cols meaning different things... (for example different logos on each row, selected/hovered on right, plain on left) In that case, I'd suggest to separate the big picture in separate images, or write the different combinations in the CSS... Depending on the number of sprites, one or the other could be the best choice.

Mine has the exact problem as stated by Orabîg which has a table like sprite which has columns and rows.

Below is what I used as a workaround using js

```
firefoxFixBackgroundposition:function(){
  $('.circle').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
       $(this).css('background-position',$(this).css('background-position').split(' ')[0]+' -10px');   
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
       $(this).css('background-position',$(this).css('background-position').split(' ')[0]+' 0');   
    }
  });      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make certain you explicitly state the measurement of your offset. I came across this exact issue today, and it was due to how browsers interpret the values you provide in your CSS.

For example, this works perfectly in Chrome:

```
background: url("my-image.png") 100 100 no-repeat;
```

But, for Firefox and IE, you need to write:

```
background: url("my-image.png") 100px 100px no-repeat;
```

Hope this helps.