# CSS variables and animation

Tags: css, firefox, animation, css-animations, css-variables

I was trying to make a "multi-row" sprite CSS animation (insipred by this: http://codepen.io/simurai/pen/vmhuJ), only to find that Firefox doesn't support `background-position-x` or `-y`.

The lack of `-x/-y` is discussed at length here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=550426, and a proposed solution ([background-position-y doesn't work in Firefox (via CSS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844407/background-position-y-doesnt-work-in-firefox-via-css/29282573#29282573)) is to use **CSS variables**, which were recently introduced in Firefox.

However, it doesn't look like updating CSS variables from animation `@keyframes` is supported?

```
...
background-position: var(--bgX) var(--bgY);
...

/*Here, CSS variables don't work:*/
@keyframes move-y {
  from {
    --bgY: 0px;
  }
  to {
    --bgY: -670px;
  }
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle (note: *Firefox only*): http://jsfiddle.net/phoj0kq5/
I added flickering borders to the animation just to make sure it's running, but the crab doesn't snap its fingers.. Am I using CSS variables wrong, or do they simply not support animation?

**Edit**

Updated fiddle which actually works in Chrome (still not in Firefox): http://jsfiddle.net/phoj0kq5/1/

Comment: The css-variables spec discusses the behavior of custom properties with respect to animations (see [§2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#syntax) and [§3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#using-variables)), but as I'm not too familiar with animations I can't comment further.

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks, that's good information. I don't really understand what they are saying either, but "tainted" doesn't sound promising...

Comment: you use scss for variables use this http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: @lyndact - SCSS is compiled to normal CSS before it can be used, so I don't see how that can help here. This question is about the new feature [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but a workaround that should help:

Since you cannot show a part of the image dynamically when cols and rows are changing one at a time, try using only one column or row of image parts.

When only one line of sub-images is used, you should be able to set the viewed part with `background-position: X 0;` while X is your offset per image. You will need to edit the image file you are showing to achieve this.

So change the layout of subimages in the image file form:

```
☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺
```

to:

```
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
```

As i said, this is not a solution to the problem itself and rather a workaround, but it should work fine on all browsers. However, Mozilla should implement the -x/-y attributes or fix the CSS-variable issue in animations. Until then, i don't see a proper solution for this.

Comment: Thanks! Yes that would enable you to do sprite animations, but the real question here is how to use the new CSS variables in animation. Sorry if  that wasn't clear.

Comment: Yes what i did there is really just a workaround because the animations cause such problems with variables. I think this is a Mozilla related issue and they should fix it. As long as they won't solve this problem the workaround should be fine, although it needs image editing skills and takes extra time. I'm sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use this neat trick!

```
.element {
    animation: move-y 1s;
    background-position: var(--bgX) var(--bgY);
}

@keyframes move-y {
  0% {
    --bgY: 0;
  }

  1% {
    --bgY: 1px;
  }

  2% {
    --bgY: 2px;
  }

  3% {
    --bgY: 3px;
  }

  4% {
    --bgY: 4px;
  }

  5% {
    --bgY: 5px;
  }

  6% {
    --bgY: 6px;
  }

  7% {
    --bgY: 7px;
  }

  8% {
    --bgY: 8px;
  }

  9% {
    --bgY: 9px;
  }

  10% {
    --bgY: 10px;
  }

  11% {
    --bgY: 11px;
  }

  12% {
    --bgY: 12px;
  }

  13% {
    --bgY: 13px;
  }

  14% {
    --bgY: 14px;
  }

  15% {
    --bgY: 15px;
  }

  16% {
    --bgY: 16px;
  }

  17% {
    --bgY: 17px;
  }

  18% {
    --bgY: 18px;
  }

  19% {
    --bgY: 19px;
  }

  20% {
    --bgY: 20px;
  }

  21% {
    --bgY: 21px;
  }

  22% {
    --bgY: 22px;
  }

  23% {
    --bgY: 23px;
  }

  24% {
    --bgY: 24px;
  }

  25% {
    --bgY: 25px;
  }

  26% {
    --bgY: 26px;
  }

  27% {
    --bgY: 27px;
  }

  28% {
    --bgY: 28px;
  }

  29% {
    --bgY: 29px;
  }

  30% {
    --bgY: 30px;
  }

  31% {
    --bgY: 31px;
  }

  32% {
    --bgY: 32px;
  }

  33% {
    --bgY: 33px;
  }

  34% {
    --bgY: 34px;
  }

  35% {
    --bgY: 35px;
  }

  36% {
    --bgY: 36px;
  }

  37% {
    --bgY: 37px;
  }

  38% {
    --bgY: 38px;
  }

  39% {
    --bgY: 39px;
  }

  40% {
    --bgY: 40px;
  }

  41% {
    --bgY: 41px;
  }

  42% {
    --bgY: 42px;
  }

  43% {
    --bgY: 43px;
  }

  44% {
    --bgY: 44px;
  }

  45% {
    --bgY: 45px;
  }

  46% {
    --bgY: 46px;
  }

  47% {
    --bgY: 47px;
  }

  48% {
    --bgY: 48px;
  }

  49% {
    --bgY: 49px;
  }

  50% {
    --bgY: 50px;
  }

  51% {
    --bgY: 51px;
  }

  52% {
    --bgY: 52px;
  }

  53% {
    --bgY: 53px;
  }

  54% {
    --bgY: 54px;
  }

  55% {
    --bgY: 55px;
  }

  56% {
    --bgY: 56px;
  }

  57% {
    --bgY: 57px;
  }

  58% {
    --bgY: 58px;
  }

  59% {
    --bgY: 59px;
  }

  60% {
    --bgY: 60px;
  }

  61% {
    --bgY: 61px;
  }

  62% {
    --bgY: 62px;
  }

  63% {
    --bgY: 63px;
  }

  64% {
    --bgY: 64px;
  }

  65% {
    --bgY: 65px;
  }

  66% {
    --bgY: 66px;
  }

  67% {
    --bgY: 67px;
  }

  68% {
    --bgY: 68px;
  }

  69% {
    --bgY: 69px;
  }

  70% {
    --bgY: 70px;
  }

  71% {
    --bgY: 71px;
  }

  72% {
    --bgY: 72px;
  }

  73% {
    --bgY: 73px;
  }

  74% {
    --bgY: 74px;
  }

  75% {
    --bgY: 75px;
  }

  76% {
    --bgY: 76px;
  }

  77% {
    --bgY: 77px;
  }

  78% {
    --bgY: 78px;
  }

  79% {
    --bgY: 79px;
  }

  80% {
    --bgY: 80px;
  }

  81% {
    --bgY: 81px;
  }

  82% {
    --bgY: 82px;
  }

  83% {
    --bgY: 83px;
  }

  84% {
    --bgY: 84px;
  }

  85% {
    --bgY: 85px;
  }

  86% {
    --bgY: 86px;
  }

  87% {
    --bgY: 87px;
  }

  88% {
    --bgY: 88px;
  }

  89% {
    --bgY: 89px;
  }

  90% {
    --bgY: 90px;
  }

  91% {
    --bgY: 91px;
  }

  92% {
    --bgY: 92px;
  }

  93% {
    --bgY: 93px;
  }

  94% {
    --bgY: 94px;
  }

  95% {
    --bgY: 95px;
  }

  96% {
    --bgY: 96px;
  }

  97% {
    --bgY: 97px;
  }

  98% {
    --bgY: 98px;
  }

  99% {
    --bgY: 99px;
  }

  100% {
    --bgY: 100px;
  }
}
```

The reason that this works is that the browser doesn't actually know how to move from "0" to "100px". Because these values aren't real numbers. They're strings! So, it makes sense to guide the browser in every step and tell it what to do.

Although there are two downsides to this. The first one obviously is that its big. I personally wouldn't mind that. what I would mind is that you have to calculate every step if it isn't as "simple" as the one I showed you. Let me explain:

It is "simple" if the difference between start and end points is 100 or something relatable. Which was the case in our example.

And it is not "simple" if otherwise, which causes something like this:

```
...
  0% {
    --bgY: 0;
  }

  1% {
    --bgY: 0.3px;
  }

  2% {
    --bgY: 0.6px;
  }
...
```

With Everything said, this isn't something that a custom string generator wouldn't pull off. So, I would consider this the best way to change CSS vars with animation.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work in Firefox..