# css background-position cross browser

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

I'm using a sprite image containing several buttons with their state.
background-position is working in Chrome and Edge but not in Firefox!

Fiddle: (If you run this in Chrome/edge it works, but not in firefox)
https://jsfiddle.net/bkgrnnmu/1/

The layout of the sprite image:

```
         buttons
         _ _ _ _ _ 
Normal: |_|_|_|_|_|
Hover:  |_|_|_|_|_|
Click:  |_|_|_|_|_|
Dis:    |_|_|_|_|_|
```

I also noticed that

```
background-position-x
background-position-y
```

is rarely used css, is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Which version of Firefox? See [support table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-position-x-y).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [background-position-y doesn't work in Firefox (via CSS)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844407/background-position-y-doesnt-work-in-firefox-via-css)

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't support background-position-x or background-position-y. Try background-position: 0 0; first condition is x, second y.